# encoding then decoding not giving same output

Tags: encoding, decoding

In this Program : 
java.util.Base64 library is used.

`byte[] bytes = "Test String".getBytes();
    String s = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
    byte[] b2 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
    if(b2.equals(bytes)) System.out.println("True");
    else System.out.println("False");`

Output is: False

Comment: Try with `Arrays.equals`.

Comment: yup that works Thanks. But why Printing both bytes and b2 gives different output. `bytes : [B@4cdf35a9
b2 : [B@4c98385c`

Comment: For arrays, Java (JVM) do not override the `hashCode`, `equals`, `toString` methods. That is the reason that `equals` practically is just `==` and the `toString` of the two arrays are different. You should use the methods of `java.util.Arrays` for these kinds of tasks when you are working with arrays.